# How to map /sys/bus/usb/devices to /dev/video*?

Tags: linux, usb, devices, video, sysfs

I am using a library (librealsense) that only outputs the bus and port number as such (9.1). It uses libusb internally. The issue is from this identifier in libusb I want to know what physical device it belongs to in /dev/video0. For instance, 9.1 -> /dev/video0 and 7.2 -> /dev/video2 when two cameras are plugged in in ports 9.1 and 7.2.

Is this possible? How do I acquire what devices paths belong to a bus and port? Any partial answer would be helpful.

Comment: Don't know your OS, but if the devices are created via `udev`, you could use `udevadm info -n video0 -q all` to see the created symlinks; e.g. `S: v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:13.2-usb-0:4.1:1.0-video-index0` shows the link in `/dev/v4l/by-path`. Or, if you know the ID of your cameras, `/dev/v4l/by-id`could help. And configuring `udev` might give fixed devices for different cameras.

Comment: You can do it the other way round (find which usb device belongs to which `video*` device) by examining `/sys/class/video4linux/`, which contains symlinks with the complete bus path (usb or otherwise).

Comment: @ridgy Thanks that's what I was looking for, I can grep for existence of that path! Feel free to copy that as an answer, if you want.

Comment: @dirkt I appreciate your answer, I tried that but I'm not quite sure which directory the video information is location within the /sys/class/video4linux folder.

Comment: Just do `ls -l /sys/class/video4linux/`, you should see all video devices as symlinks. `udevadm` also just looks at the `/sys` file system, but extracts more information from it (most of which you don't need for your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering so I can close this question full credit to @ridgy and @dirkt for their help. With the command:

```
udevadm info -n video0 -q path
```

Or similarly with `ls -l /sys/class/video4linux/`, a path of the form `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.0/video4linux/video0` can be found. That in combination with the listing of the video devices using either `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` allows a map between the usb port and video device to be created.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below command to get more information

> > udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video0)
> >
> > udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video1)